# How can I insert a QR code reader in my django application to verify if a code exists on the database?

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, qr-code

I have a django app of musical show tickets that a QR code is generated and saved on the database after every sale of a ticket. Now I'm trying to create a page that will read these QR codes to verify if it exists on the database.

HTML:

```
<h1>QR code reader</h1>
<video name="qr-video" id="qr-video" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay></video>

<script>
    const video = document.getElementById('qr-video');

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { facingMode: 'environment' } })
        .then((stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
                    resolve();
                };
            });
        })
        .then(() => {
            video.play();
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            setInterval(() => {
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const imageData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const code = jsQR(imageData.data, imageData.width, imageData.height);
                if (code) {
                    alert('QR code read: ' + code.data);
                    sendQRcode(code.data);
                }
            }, 1000);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error trying to access camera: ', error);
        });

    function sendQRcode(code) {
        alert('QR code sent')
        const url = 'https://ac7-1bd37c9a12e8.herokuapp.com/show/scanner/';
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken')
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ code: code}),
        })
        .then((response) => {
            response.text().then((text) => {
                alert('Response from server:', text);
            });
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                alert('Response not ok')
            }
            return response.json();
        })

        .then((data) => {
            alert('Response from server: ' + data.message);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            alert('Error on the AJAX request:', error);
        });
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
</script>
```

```
Views.py

@csrf_exempt
def scanner(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        qr_code_data = data.get('code')

        if qr_code_data:
            try:
                payment = UserPayment.objects.get(stripe_checkout_id=qr_code_data)
                message = 'Valid QR code!'
            except UserPayment.DoesNotExist:
                message = 'Invalid QR code!'
        else:
            message = 'QR code data don't exist.'

        return JsonResponse({'message': message})
    else:
        return render(request, 'scanner.html')
```

models.py:

```
class UserPayment(models.Model):
    app_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    payment_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    stripe_checkout_id = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    qr_code = models.ImageField(upload_to='qr_codes', null=True, blank=True)
```

When I read the QR code on the phone, It shows an alert saying: "QR code read", "QR code sent", "Error on the AJAX request" e "Response from server: " (without the response from server)

Comment: `response.text()` will "use" the body, therefore `response.json()` will fail -having said that, you'd expect to see the `response from server` for the `response.text()` call, perhaps the server is responding with nothing

Comment: by the way, if `response.ok` is false, you'd never see `alert('Response not ok')` since you `throw` an error before that line

Comment: at a guess though, the reason you can't see the response from the server is due to CORS

Comment: I've removed the throw of the error and it showed the alert "response not ok"

Comment: well, now you know what you're looking for